# Single column for multiple rows within WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, where-clause, mariadb

I'm attempting to consolidate the where clause on the column name.  I require a single column to return positive on the condition, but the same condition applies for many columns.  The brute force example is below, to check for dates between a certain range on several columns.  I have the columns OR'd with the exact same condition.

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE foo.date1 BETWEEN DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 16 HOUR), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) and DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 16 HOUR)
OR foo.date2 BETWEEN DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 16 HOUR), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 16 HOUR);
```

I would prefer to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE (foo.date1 OR foo.date2) BETWEEN DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 16 HOUR), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) and DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 16 HOUR);
```

.. but have it still work for individual columns across rows.

I'm using MariaDB, but can adapt any solutions from other flavors of sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first works; the second is bad syntax.

I prefer

```
BETWEEN NOW() + INTERVAL 16-24 HOUR
    AND NOW() + INTERVAL 16    HOUR
```

If the `16` is due to timezones, consider using `TIMESTAMP` and/or setting your system time appropriately.